# Pandas groupby referece column

Tags: python, pandas

I concatenated a few Pandas dataframe and now I have one larger dataframe.
The initial dataframes look like this

```
   Time  Node  Packets
0     1     0        0
2     1     1        0
4     1     2        0
6     1     3        0
8     1     4        0
```

And the concatenated one looks like this after running `df_total = df_total.groupby(['Time'])['Packets'].mean()`

```
Time
1.0      0.000000
2.0      1.250000
3.0      3.880952
4.0      6.797619
5.0     12.345238
```

As you can see, the column header `Packets` is gone. The problem is that I'm using Seaborn to plot the time x packets.

How do I call Seaborn lineplot using the concatenated dataframe?

sns.lineplot(df['???'], legend=False, ax=ax1)

I tried using `sns.lineplot(df[''])` but it didn't work.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Time'],as_index=False)['Packets'].mean()
`

Comment: This worked the best for me, as the other solutions increase the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['Time'],as_index=False)['Packets'].transform('mean')
```

Should do the trick, but you will have repeated columns with multiple values for the mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transform` function to add Packets mean as a column in your DataFrame:

`df_total['Packets_mean'] = df_total.groupby(['Time'])['Packets'].transform('mean')`